# Convert quarter-year to MM/DD/YYYY in Excel

Tags: excel, date

How to convert this quarter-year format into MM/DD/YYYY in Excel where quarter will convert to first day of quarter. For example,
Q1-2014 to 1/1/2014, 
Q2-2015 to 4/1/2015, 
Q3-2016 to 7/1/2016, 
Q4-2017 to 10/1/2017

Comment: `= MID(A1, 2, 1) * 3 - 2 & "/1/" & RIGHT(A1, 4)`

Comment: @Slai That returns text, not a date

Comment: @teylyn It's intentional because the askers locale is unknown

Comment: Thanks Slai!  This works perfectly.

Comment: @Slai So you force US date notation on every user who wants to try this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

`=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),(MID(A1,2,1)*3)-2,1)`

That will return a date. Format to display in whatever date format you want.

Comment: Thanks Teylyn!  Love the elegant formula.  However, the year came out with only 2 digits.

Comment: @user3068093 you can change the cell Custom Format to `M/d/yyyy` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula you could use

```
=DATE(MID(A1,4,4),IF(MID(A1,1,2)= "Q1", 1, IF(MID(A1, 1, 2) = "Q2", 4, IF(MID(A1,1,2)="Q3", 7, 10))), 1)
```

Assumptions
The format is Q[1/2/3/4]-YYYY

Formula
Take the last 4 digits as Year
Take Month as 1 if Q1 else 3 if month is Q3,...
Take Date as 1

Comment: The formula can be simplified as @teylyn mentioned below.

Comment: Thanks @Dgorti!  Yes, @Teylyn's formula is simple and elegant.